# Run function after ngFor finishes

Tags: angular

I am having an issue with bindings.

I have the following snippet:

```html
<div class="columns" *ngFor="let prop of proprietiesList; let i = index">
    <div class="column is-one-quarter">
        <label>{{prop.prop_nome}}</label>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="select">
            <select [id]="'options'+i" #product>
                <option [value]="opt.prop_opcao_preco" *ngFor="let opt of prop.options">{{opt.prop_opcao_nome}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>   
    </div>
</div>
```

My objective is to run a function, on the component load, that prints all the values that are selected in each `select` element.
I have tried this:

```js
calculaPreco(): void{
    for(let i = 0; i<this.proprietiesList.length; i++){
      this.selectPriceArray.push((<HTMLInputElement>(document.getElementById("options"+i))).value);
    }
}
```

This function is called as:

```js
this.proprietiesList = data;
this.calculaPreco();
```

However, this gets me the following error:

> Cannot read property 'value' of null

Meaning that, at this point, the select element doesn't yet exist. Any clues on how to solve this?
I tried the `ngAfterViewInit` to run the function but no luck.

Comment: You wouldn't use document.getElementById() in angular. You'd also never retrieve the values from a html element. Instead, get the array you want to create with a simple map over proprietesList in your component

Answer (score 0):

Might be a better way but here is what I will try:

```html
<div class="columns" *ngFor="let prop of proprietiesList; let i = index">
    <div class="column is-one-quarter">
        <label>{{prop.prop_nome}}</label>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="select">
            <select [id]="'options'+i" #product>
                <option [value]="opt.prop_opcao_preco" *ngFor="let opt of prop.options">{{opt.prop_opcao_nome}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="index === proprietiesList.length && this.calculaPreco()"></div>
</div>
```

Using the **index** to check wether we are on the **last item of the list**, calcularPreco will execute **only after every element has been generated** and just once.

Answer (score 0):

`ngAfterViewChecked` should work

```
// When change detection has finished:
// child components created, all *ngIfs evaluated

ngAfterViewChecked() {
  this.calculaPreco(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No answer really helped me, I defined an empty option in my selects and I added the value of the select to the array with the `onChange` function.

Thank you all anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the best solutions would be to use a directive to capture the last element.

```
  export class IsLastItemDirective {
  @Output() onLastItem = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  @Input() set isLastItem(value: boolean) {
    if (value) {
      this.onLastItem.emit(true);
    }
  }
  constructor() { }
  }
```

This way you could capture your last NgFor loop and fire your function

```
 <div *ngFor="let item of items; let l=last">
        <div [isLastItem]="l" (onLastItem)="functionOnLastItem()">
          <span>{{item.name}}</span>
        </div>
</div>
```

It's too late, but maybe it can help someone or someone has a better idea.